# Better way to install helm with Ansible?

Tags: ansible

The following recipe works, but I find the number of tasks being high and I'm wondering if there is a better way to install Helm while performing a checksum. Currently, I have to:

1. Check current installed helm version, if any
2. Download helm and notify the handler to unarchive the binary
3. Unarchive the binary, if needed
4. Delete downloaded file, if needed

`roles/node/tasks/main.yaml`:

```yaml
- name: Set current helm version
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: helm version --client --template={{ "'{{ .Version }}'" }}
  changed_when: false
  failed_when: false
  register: current_helm_version

- name: Download helm archive
  ansible.builtin.get_url:
    url: https://get.helm.sh/helm-{{ helm_version }}-linux-arm64.tar.gz
    checksum: sha256:https://get.helm.sh/helm-{{ helm_version }}-linux-arm64.tar.gz.sha256sum
    dest: /tmp
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  notify: Unarchive helm binary
  when: helm_version != current_helm_version.stdout | default(false)

- name: Flush handlers
  ansible.builtin.meta: flush_handlers

- name: Delete helm archive
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /tmp/helm-{{ helm_version }}-linux-arm64.tar.gz
    state: absent
```

`roles/node/handlers/main.yaml`:

```yaml
- name: Unarchive helm binary
  ansible.builtin.unarchive:
    src: /tmp/helm-{{ helm_version }}-linux-arm64.tar.gz
    dest: /usr/local/bin
    extra_opts: "--strip-components=1"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0755
    remote_src: true
```

Comment: I didn't understand where you stuck? either you didn't tried complete plan or doubt on something. please express it!

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with one single task:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Install helm if not exists
      unarchive:
        src: https://get.helm.sh/helm-v3.11.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz
        dest: /usr/local/bin
        extra_opts: "--strip-components=1"
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0755
        remote_src: true
      args:
        creates: /usr/local/bin/helm
```

When `/usr/local/bin/helm` exists, it will not execute the task.

Comment: While the suggestion is useful, I need to perform a checksum.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with. It will install latest version if *helm_version* is not specified. It will not do anything if */usr/local/bin/helm* is already present.

```yaml
---
- name: Download Helm command line tool
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/main/scripts/get-helm-3
    return_content: true
  register: helm_installer

- name: Install Helm
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: bash
    stdin: "{{ helm_installer.content }}"
    creates: /usr/local/bin/helm
  environment:
    DESIRED_VERSION: "{{ helm_version | default('') }}"
```